# Sed replace entire line after match in XML

Tags: xml, bash, sed

I want to replace a line in an XML once I identify the correct tag.

Take

```
<root>
    <My_Name>Andrew</My_Name>
    <My_Age>94</My_Age>
</root>
```

I would like to replace
Andrew
with 
Bob

where Bob is stored in $nameVariable

Using sed,

```
sed -i 's/<My_Name>.*</My_Name>/<My_Name>$nameVariable</My_Name>/g'
```

This is probably failing due to the lack of escape characters, which I've tried putting in different places, but don't seem to get them right.
Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Use double quote to expand variable and escape the  `/`, see my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `awk` may work:

```
awk -v name="$nameVariable" '/<My_Name>/{sub(/>.*</,">"name"<")}1' file
<root>
    <My_Name>Bob</My_Name>
    <My_Age>94</My_Age>
</root>
```

---

To fix your  `sed`.  Use double quote and escape the `/`

```
sed -i "s/<My_Name>.*<\/My_Name>/<My_Name>$nameVariable<\/My_Name>/g" file
<root>
    <My_Name>Bob</My_Name>
    <My_Age>94</My_Age>
</root>
```

You can change it some so you do not need text two times:

```
sed  -i -r "s|(<My_Name>).*(</My_Name>)|\1$nameVariable\2|g" file
```

`-r` so I do not need to escape the `()`.
Replace `/` with `|` so no escape of `/` is needed.

Comment: @Marty You are welcome.  Updated post some.

Answer (score 0):

sed is not a good tool to edit XML. Whichever way you do it, it's going to break if there's a newline in the wrong place, or if there's an empty tag, or if there are nested tags, or in a gazillion other cases.

Use a tool that parses XML properly. For example, with xmlstarlet:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u '/root/My_Name' -v "$nameVariable" filename.xml
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Still, the script will be running on multiple machines on which sed is the tool that can be used and others cannot be imposed. The format of the original XML though, will be strictly imposed and the risks assumed.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regular expressions to handle XML. Use a proper XML handling tool. For example, I use [xsh](http://p3rl.org/XML::XSH2):

The script:

```
open file.xml ;
set /root/My_Name { $ARGV[0] } ;
save :b ;
```

Invocation:

```
xsh script.xsh "$nameVariable"
```